# How to use some of ListView method in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm used  **RecyclerView** for show and sort levels. because **ListView** has slowly speed I did not use listView and use RecyclerView. 
Therefore, I need some of the `ListView`methods, this methods has `SetScrollPosition` and `SetOnItemSelect` .

My RecyclerView Adapter codes :

```
public class levels_card_adapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder> {
private static String[] adapter_levels_number;

public levels_card_adapter(String[] adapter_levels_num_data) {
    adapter_levels_number = adapter_levels_num_data;



}

@Override
public levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.levels_recycler_layout, null);


    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.adapter_levels_text.setText(adapter_levels_number[position].toString());

    viewHolder.adapter_levels_version = adapter_levels_number[position];



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adapter_levels_number.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView adapter_levels_text;

    public String adapter_levels_version;


    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        adapter_levels_text = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.level_thumnail_text);

        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent question_page_intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), com.tellfa.braingame.activities.question_Page.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(question_page_intent);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Activity Code :

```
public class play_Page extends ActionBarActivity {

private RecyclerView play_recycler_levels;
private RecyclerView.Adapter play_adapter_levels;
private TextView play_header_text;
private tellfa_textView play_thumbnail_levels_num, play_time_level_num;
private DiscreteSeekBar play_scroll_seekbar;
private com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle fb;
private Context context;
private ListView play_list_levels;

public static String[] levels_number = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play__page);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    ///////////// Font Style
    Typeface yekan_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yekan.ttf");

    play_header_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_play_text);
    play_header_text.setTypeface(yekan_font);
    /////////////

    play_thumbnail_levels_num = (tellfa_textView) findViewById(R.id.level_thumnail_text);

    play_time_level_num = (tellfa_textView) findViewById(R.id.time_levels_num);

    ///////////// SeekBar
    play_scroll_seekbar = (DiscreteSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.scroll_seekbar_play);



    ///////////// Recycler View
    play_recycler_levels = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.levels_recycler);

    play_recycler_levels.setHasFixedSize(true);

    play_recycler_levels.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    play_adapter_levels = new levels_card_adapter(levels_number);

    play_recycler_levels.setAdapter(play_adapter_levels);

    ////////////

    /*
    //////////// List
    com.tellfa.braingame.adapters.levels_list_adapter adapter=new com.tellfa.braingame.adapters.levels_list_adapter
            (this, levels_number);
    play_list_levels=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    play_list_levels.setAdapter(adapter);
    play_list_levels.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);
        ///////////
    */

    FrameLayout containerLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_id);
    HeaderAnimator animator = new HeaderAnimator(this);

    StikkyHeaderBuilder.stickTo(play_recycler_levels)
            .setHeader(R.id.header, containerLayout)
            .minHeightHeader(250)
            .animator(animator)
            .build();

    ///////////// Refresh
    final SwipeRefreshLayout play_refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh_play_layout);
    play_refresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh1, R.color.refresh2, R.color.refresh3, R.color.refresh4, R.color.refresh5);
    play_refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            play_refresh.setRefreshing(true);

        }
    });

}
```

How can I make this method?
**this is very important for me**

Answer (score 0):

What about [setScrollX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollX(int)) and [RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html)?

> public void setScrollX (int value)
>
> Set the horizontal scrolled position of your view.

RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener

> An OnItemTouchListener allows the application to intercept touch
>   events in progress at the view hierarchy level of the RecyclerView
>   before those touch events are considered for RecyclerView's own
>   scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like that and the only way of scrolling with the RecyclerView is calculating the position manually and scrolling with the LayoutManager that you are using.

I used these 2 methods in my adapter to achieve this, if you find out that it helps you out use it:

```
public void scrollToPosition(int positionToScrollTo) {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = null;
    try {
        layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        log.d("You should pass a recyclerview with a layoutmanayer" +
                "that inherits from LinearLayoutManager");
        return;
    }
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    View firstVisibleItemView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleItemPosition);
    int firstViewHeight = firstVisibleItemView.getHeight();
    int scrollOffsetVertical = firstViewHeight * positionToScrollTo;
    mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, scrollOffsetVertical);
}

public void smoothScrollToPosition(int positionToSCroll) {
    for (int i = 0;i < positionToSCroll; i++) {
        scrollToPosition(i);
    }

}
```

There should be better ways to do this but this worked for me, hope it helps, Good luck...

Comment: Thank you dear friend.can you the above statements coordinate with my codes and give me?

Comment: They should work just make an instance of your RecyclerView in your RecyclerAdapter called mRecyclerView and place these methods inside your RecyclerAdapter then test the methods...